# Granting Administrator Privileges to file as Standard user

Tags: windows, administrator

When running a program as a standard user, I want to run one file as an administrator therefore when the program is run as a standard user and requires access to the file which must have administrator access
it can read and write to the file ?

The problem with running most programs as a administrator within a standard account is; if you are like myself, you have the program setup more or less how you want; run the same program as an administrator 
within a standard account, and your preferences etc are eliminated because it's reading the preferences from the administrator account for the program within the standard account; unless one knows how to 
transfer preferences etc for a program from the standard account user to the administrator and there is no difference ?

Comment: It’s not clear if your question is that you want a program to run as administrator, or if you want a standard user to be able to change a specific file? It sounds like you want a user to be able to modify a specific file and your solution you are presenting us with is to run the application as admin. This is wrong. Change the permissions on the file and make it modifiable by a standard user.

Comment: This would only be possible if you had full control over the file as a normal user, only then could you add a user or user group to the ACL, otherwise you must use an Administrator to do that.

Comment: @Appleoddity You mention to change the permissions on the file and make it modificable by a standard user, how so ? Hoping the program does not need to be run as an administrator for it to read the file as an administrator file.

Comment: @Ramhound ACL ? I could run the program leaving the standard user preferences as it, but run the program as an administrator ?

Comment: Just right-click the file and change the permissions to allow the “users” group or the specific user to modify the file. Look up changing NTFS permissions. I don’t know what an “administrator file” is. I’m assuming you’re referring to a file/folder that has permissions which require an a user to be in the “administrators” group to access.

Comment: There is a workaround where you place a shortcut and in the shortcut properties you add before the file path “run as”  command and then a cmd pops up and prompts your password Once and then the user will be able to run it as an administrator every time  without your interaction

Comment: To which preferences are you referring?

Comment: @harrymc It's a preference file for an IDE.

Comment: Which IDE is it?

Comment: @harrymc Visual Studio Code

Comment: @Appleoddity Are you saying, right-click on a file then go to the `security` tab then add `administrator` privileges to the file ? If so, the current user which is not an administrator has to be placed within a group, otherwise it can't be added since I can't select the current standard user and add it for the file which I want to be run as an administrator.

Comment: No offense. But your concept of this is backwards. That is why I suggested you read up on NTFS permissions and users and groups management. You don’t “add administrator privileges” to the file. You *grant* a *user* or *group* certain permissions on a *file* or *folder*. I don’t know why you keep saying “I want to run a file as administrator.” Your description of what you want, which I think I understand, does not fit the terminology you are using. You want to allow a standard user and the application they are running to access a specific file. So grant that user permissions on the file.

Comment: There is no such thing as an “administrator file.” A file has an access control list. Whatever user / group is in that list will have the permissions specified. That’s it.

Comment: @Appleoddity It is only the terminology which I'm using, I know that you must grant a user or group certain permissions on a file or folder, it is so we both are understanding each other regardless of terminology; since you are understand I and I am understanding you, this is good.  On that note, I **can't** add any `user` or `group` to the file; as there is nothing to select for *select users or groups* for file file ?